# Run two macros for active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run two macros in any active cell of the sheet. I might need to go back to the cell which i ran macros earlier to run same macros again. So, I might have to go back to same cells multiple times to run same two macros. So, How do I run two macros for any cell in a sheet? I'd appreciate any help. Please and thank you!

I created macros for cells I might need but it looks really tacky and it is not user-friendly

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To run 2 macros on the activecell, create a new macro, typically named "Main" or something similar. From the main macro, call each of the other 2 macros. When calling the other 2 macros, pass the activecell as a parameter.

```
Sub main()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveCell

Call macro1(rng)
Call macro2(rng)

End Sub



Sub macro1(rng As Range)

rng = rng & "Macro1 complete."

End Sub



Sub macro2(rng As Range)

rng = rng & "Macro2 complete."

End Sub
```